# C: first number in array becomes 0 for unknown reason

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

**The Program:**

This was supposed to be a simple reverse polish notation addition program, please ignore the EOF break thing, it's a placeholder. 
Input is c, always one numeral number, it gets transfered to x where every next numeral c will be added to the number x, so for example when we input c as 1,2 and 3 x will be 123. 
When we input 'e' it will mark the start of a new number, and x will be transfered to the stack[0] after the entire stack gets pushed back, and x will become 0. When inputing '+' addition happens, the last two numbers will be summed, x and the first number in the stack, or the first and second number in the stack, or the first number in the stack will duplicate itself. 
**The Problem:**
The first number in the stack array will randomly become 0 and I cannot see where I made the error. The first number (stack[0]) only gets the value zero at the start, never again. At times when inputting '+' it will just get a value.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int stack[16];
    int x;
    int i;
    char c;
    //int c;
    x=0;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            stack[i]=0;
        }

    while(1)
    {
        //input character
        scanf("%s", &c);

        if (c == EOF) break;
        //put x to stack
        else if (c == 'e')
            {for (i = 15; i >0; i--)
            {
                stack[i]=stack[i-1];
            }
        stack[0] = x;
        x = 0;
        }
        //reverse polish addition
        else if (c == '+')
            //if x is 0 go immediately to the stack
            {if (x == 0)
                    //if both x and the second number in array are 0 just duplicate the first number
                  if (stack[1] == 0)
                    stack[0] = stack[0] + stack[0];
                    //if only x is 0 add the first number on the second
                  else
                  {
                stack[0]=stack[0]+stack[1];
                //push back the array to fill the gap on the second number
                for (i = 1; i <15; i++)
                {
                    stack[i]=stack[i+1];
                }

            }
            else
            {
                stack[0] = stack[0] + x;
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        x = x * 10 + ((int)c-0x30);
        // putchar(c);
        }
        printf("X=%d\n",x);
        //print stack
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            printf("%d \t",stack[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &c);` causes undefined behavior. Use `scanf("%c", &c);`.

Comment: Hard to follow your code when its so poorly formatted

Comment: I caught that -- eyes play tricks with ill formatted code...

Comment: I would recommend reading up a bit on how to create a stack.  This methodology is not very efficient as you have to copy the entire stack everytime you push or pop something.  You can simplify the copying by getting rid of the loops and instead using `memmove`, but that's still rather inefficient compared to using a pointer (or simply an index) to the top of the stack.

Comment: Thank you all, I will look on the net how to create a stack with pointers or an index.
Replacing %s with %c makes it actually worse because x becomes a random number, I assume it has something to do with the     
x = x * 10 + ((int)c-0x30);

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem 1

`scanf("%s", &c);` causes undefined behavior. Use `scanf(" %c", &c);`.

#### Problem 2

`c` is never going to be equal to `EOF` by using `scanf`. Hence, the following line is useless.

```
    if (c == EOF) break;
```

---

The following will take care of both problems.

```
// Use " %c" instead of "%c" to skip leading whitespace characters.
while ( scanf(" %c", &c) == 1 )
{
}
```

Comment: Using %c causes x to get random numbers, I will look how to make stacks with pointers like mentioned above

Comment: @happydude, Please try again with my suggested change for `x`.

Comment: `x` was not uninitialized; it's set to `0` after `char c` was declared.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, good point. There must be some other error in the OP's code.